# GoogleScripts - How to send email based on cell value

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am a beginner with Google Scripts and was wanting to send emails based on a cell value within a Google Sheet.

The cell which determines whether an email is to be sent is C2 in the Sheet 'FloodEWS'.

If the value is equal to or above 270, I need to send a specific email.
If the value is equal to or greater than 310, I need to send a different email.

[image]

The script I have so far is this:

```
function amberwarning() {
  // Fetch the combined flow value
  var combflowrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FloodEWS").getRange("C2"); 
  var combflow = combflowrange.getValue();
  // Check combined flow value
  if (270 < combflow < 310){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("A2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'It is possible that the Egger site will experience flooding in the coming hours. The advice is to be prepared to take action as combined river flows can increase very quickly during storms. Please keep up to date with the latest river levels for Hexham at <https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/9006>. The latest flood warnings from the Environment Agency for Hexham are here <https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/warnings?location=+hexham>. The latest MetOffice weather forecast can be found here <https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/forecast/gcy2xzrne#?>. Please use all available information to inform your decision making. You will keep receiving an email as per each refresh of the latest data. The current combined flow from the North and South Tyne is' + combflow;
    var subject = 'Amber flood warning';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:

- If value is greater than or equal to 270 and less than 310, send message 1.
- If value is greater than or equal to 310, send message 2.
- Anything else, send an error message.
- Modify the script for your requirements.

Sheet used:

```
     A          B         C
---------------------------------
1    RHF        HBF       CF
2    72.25      63.95     311
3       
4    RL         HBL       HL
5    1.566      1.015     32.014
```

```
function val() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet8")
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 5, 3);
var data = range.getValues();
var combinedFlow = data[1][2];

var customMsg_1 = "Hey Level 1" ;
var customMsg_2 = "Hey Level 2" ;

if (combinedFlow >= 270 && combinedFlow < 310)
  message = customMsg_1;
  
else if (combinedFlow >= 310)
  message = customMsg_2;
  
else
  message = "error in script";
  
MailApp.sendEmail("user@email.com", "Combined Flow", message);

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The only thing I guess that isn't the case is that if combined flow < 270, I don't want an error message, I just don't want to send an email.

Comment: Please see edited message above with my current code